# executing bat file from javascript on chrome/firefox

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, firefox

I tried running this batch file using `ActiveXobject`, but this only works on IE. Can I get a solution to run it on Chrome/Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a Firefox extension, the following code works. It launches D:\test.bat file.

```
var file        = null;
var process     = null;
var args        = [""];

// create an nsIFile for the executable
file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.initWithPath("D:\\test.bat");

// create an nsIProcess
process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

// Launch the process
process.run(false , args, args.length);
```